# Jenkins - sending email depends on console output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have an app in Java and I'd like to run the app with Jenkins.
The app could log info "[Email] example log" or throw a specific exception in some cases.

Now I'd like to use Jenkins to send e-mails after build when Jenkins see in its Console output:

- log: [Email] .....
- specific exception has been throw

I configured Editable Email Notification and Emailext (all email parameters like smtp etc are done) and I can add it to Post-build Action
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8psbf.png

but I never used Jenkins before and I don't know which trigger should I choose in that case and where/how to write 'if code' to do what I want.

EDIT: I should probably write some Pre-send Script?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to send email, then you can directly add it in the pipeline.
**Configure System**: 
Go to Manage Jenkins-> Configure System. Here scroll down to the email notification section. If you are using Gmail then type smtp.gmail.com for the SMTP server. Click on Advanced and select Use SMTP authentication. Enter your Gmail username and password. Select the Use SSL option and enter the port number as 465. Click on Apply and then Save.
**Create Jenkins Pipeline Job**:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
stages {
stage("Send Email")
   {
     steps {
                
                emailext body: 'your body', subject: 'your sububject', to: 'abc@gmail.co,'
          }
   }
 }
}
```

Above method was an example to show you how you can send email via pipeline.
**Execute your App and then send Email**:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
stages {
stage("App execution")
   {
     steps {
                // Execute your app 
                bat label: 'Execute your app', script:"yourapp.bat >log.txt "
          }
   }
stage("Send Email")
   {
     steps {
                
                emailext body: 'your body', subject: 'your sububject', to: 'abc@gmail.co,'
          }
   }
 }
}
```

**Send email based on conditions**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
stages {
stage("App execution")
   {
     steps {
                // Execute your app 
                bat label: 'Execute your app', script:"yourapp.bat >log.txt "
          }
   }
stage("Send Email")
   {
     steps {
                // You can add condition based on your log file in previous step :
                // Example : please change below code as per your logic
                // if log contains "Email" then only send email
                if(log.contains(" Email:")){
                 emailext body: 'your body', subject: 'your subject', to: 'abc@gmail.co,'
               }
          }
   }
 }
}
```